# Why are some events not shown in the Visual Studio properties window?

Tags: visual-studio

I wanted to add an event for a textbox to handle when it loses focus. I was sure I remembered some sort of `LostFocus` event, but I didn't see it in the Properties grid. But sure enough, the event exists if I access it programmatically. I'm using VS2008 - any reason why this event (and maybe others?) wasn't shown in the Properties grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Control.LostFocus` is marked with `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`. This means it will not be shown in the Properties window. For details see [`BrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx).

Here's the declaration:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public event EventHandler LostFocus
```

Comment: +1 I'm curious to know why? Is it because they want us to use Enter and Leave instead?

Answer (score 1):

LostFocus is a troublesome event, this is the fine print from the SDK docs for WM_KILLFOCUS, the underlying Windows message:

*While processing this message, do not make any function calls that display or activate a window. This causes the thread to yield control and can cause the application to stop responding to messages. For more information, see Message Deadlocks.*

Use the Leave event instead.